# Atiyah and MacDonald's commutative algebra theorem 9.3

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Atiyah and MacDonald's commutative algebra theorem 9.3 states that if $A$ is a Noeterian domain of dimension 1, then the following statements are equivalent:

- Every primary ideal in $A$ is prime power;
- Every local ring $A_\frak{p}$ for $\frak{p} \ne 0$ is a discrete valuation ring.

The book provides a hint, but I can't work it out.

---

Here is what I have tried ((1) implies (2)), assume $\frak{q}$ is primary ideal which is power of prime $\frak{p}$ i.e. $\mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{p}^k$ then we see $\frak{q}$ is $\frak{p}$-primary.

Then we can follow the proposition 4.8 which says if $S\cap \frak{p}  = \emptyset$ then $S^{-1}\frak{q}$ is $S^{-1} \frak{p}$- primary, however I don't know how to do then?

Comment: Are you sure you have it right? Consider $A=k[[×^2,x^3]]$. This is local one dimensional domain,  but not a dvr.

Comment: Thank you Mohan ,  corrected it. (I was going to sleep last night so didn't notice the mistake in the post)